# Regex Formulas in custom fields

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I want to understand the value of "?" in regex in salesforce

Like I have seen one example

```
not(regex(ccn,"((\\d{4})-){3}\d{4} | \\d{16}?"))
```

I am not getting what this pattern will produce output

I have basic idea about regex like

```
not(regex(zipcode_POstal_Code_c , "\\d{5}(-d{4}))?"))

not(regex(ssn,"[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}"))
```

I understand these simple formulas. But not the top one.

Comment: To get better support you should add additional detail on what you're trying to do.

Comment: ? in regex means one or none. The value of it in Salesforce doesn't differ from other language. As source : http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: This question should really be asked on [so]...

Answer (score 1):

`?` simply means "optional." However, the rule as written isn't quite correct, as the parentheses are not correct. It should be:

```
((\\d{4}-){3}\\d{4}|\\d{16})?
```

This would give us "the value should be blank, 4 sets of 4 numbers with dashes, or 16 numbers with no dashes."

Comment: can you suggest me some good regex example which I can see in salesforce

Comment: I Tried these values ... 1111111111111111  and 1111-1111-1111-1111 and 1111-1111-11112222... But these are not working

Comment: @neeraj There's examples in the documentation, and you can always just search the internet for more examples (try "salesforce example regex formulas"). Could you be more specific about how the formula is "not working"?

Comment: I mean to say I Tried to put the above values . but formulas is not validating for these values